# Display react-leaflet circle over Marker tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I use react-Leaflet marker to show some text on map (some hack)

It is all fine, but if the text is near to some circle component, circle component does not bind mouseover event.

I show markers on this way

```
this.shapes['texts'] && this.shapes['texts'].map(text => {
                        return (
                            <Marker key={text['id']}
                                    position={text['coordinates']}
                                    draggable={false}
                                    opacity={0.01}
                                    icon={this.mapService.createMarkerIcon()} >
                                {
                                    this.props.showText ?
                                    <Tooltip direction={"center"} permanent className={'shape-tooltip'} bringToBack={true}>
                                        {
                                            text["rotation"] ?
                                            <div style={{transform: "rotate(" + text["rotation"] + "deg)"}}>{text['text']}</div> :
                                            <div>{text['text']}</div>
                                        }
                                    </Tooltip> :
                                    null
                                }
                            </Marker>
                        );
                    })
```

and circles

```
return (
            <div className={'SeatsLayer'}>
                {
                    this.seats.map(seat => {
                        let x = parseInt(seat['xPosition'], 10);
                        let y = parseInt(seat['yPosition'], 10);
                        return (
                            <Circle onClick={() => this.props.addTicketToTicketsList(seat)}
                                    key={seat['seatLabelId']}
                                    center={[x, y]}
                                    radius={7}
                                    color={this.defaultSeatsBorderColor}
                                    fillColor={this.getColor(seat['categoryId'], seat['bookingStatusId'])}
                                    fillOpacity={0.6}
                                    weight={100}
                                    renderer={this.props.renderer}
                                    opacity={this.isSelectedSeat(seat) ? 1 : 0.01}>
                                <Tooltip direction={"top"} className={"seat-tooltip"}>
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Reihe: {seat['row']} / Sitz: {seat['seat']}</span><br />
                                        <span>{this.getCategoryName(seat['categoryId'])}</span><br />
                                        <span>Zone: {this.getZoneName(seat['zoneId'])}</span><br />
                                    </div>
                                </Tooltip>
                            </Circle>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
```

How can I set display priority to some component over marker tooltip?
I know that my requirements maybe make no sense in a geographical map but in my case, this was only known solution for this kind of a problem.

Comment: could you set up a working example over at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I had set opacity to 0.01 for marker icon.

There was always the image that is totally transparent but still above the circle.

I had just needed to hide the image in CSS and problem was solved.

```
.leaflet-marker-icon, .leaflet-marker-shadow {
    display: none !important;
}
```